# Google Map dynamics markers and polylines

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-polyline

The user insert the city of departure and destination in 2 text input, then click on the button to display on the Google Map 2 markers corresponding to the inserted cities and a Polyline between those 2 points.

Here is my code:

```
 //Global array
 var pathArray = [];
 var cities = [ origin, destination ];
 $('#button').on("click", function()  {
   reverseGeocodeCities(cities);
 });

  function reverseGeocodeCities(cities) {
   $.each(cities, function(index, value) {
     geocoder.geocode({'address': value}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        addMarkerCity(results[0].geometry.location);
     }
    });
  });
  //Create the polyline just after the loop.
   addPolyline();
 }

  function addMarkerCity(cityPosition) {
    var currentMarker = map.addMarker({
      position: cityPosition
   });
   //Add the position of the marker into the global pathArray used by addPolylineCity function.
   pathArray.push(currentMarker.getPosition());
 }

  function addPolylineCity() {
    console.log(pathArray); //Display "[]" at the first click.
    var polyline = map.drawPolyline({
    path: pathArray,
  });
```

I have 2 problems with this code: The first one is, when the user click once on the button, the markers are displayed well on the Google Map but not the polyline between the 2 markers. I have to click twice on the button to make the polyline visible. To create the polyline, I'm using the global array pathArray containing each markers position. It always display an empty array at the first click and then the proper position of the markers after the second click on the button.

The second problem is that I'm doing a simple symbol animation on the created polyline but the flow direction change time to time, if I want to do London to New York, the symbol should slide from London to New york and not the reverse (I removed this part for code simplicity). Please note that I'm using Gmaps wrapper to use Google Map features.

Thanks for your help if you know what I'm doing wrong with my code.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: There is no `map.addMarker` method in the Google Maps Javascript API.

Comment: Why a downvote? The code is complete, have nothing else to show more than this! addmarker is my function, if you don't get the code just don't take part on this topic.

Comment: How can your code be complete if `addMarker` is your function and it is not there?  Please create a _working_ example just using the posted code that exhibits your issue.

Comment: addMarker is function called inside addMarkerCity(cityPosition) visible on my code. addMarker is a function from Gmaps JS library.

Comment: Nowhere in your question (prior to now) did you mention the Gmaps JS library.

Comment: I'm going to edit now but it's so obvious that i'm using a wrapper of Google Maps.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating the polyline first and then the markers, so the polyline does not appear

```
               if (pathArray.length == 2) {
                addPolylineCity();
           }; //hardcode
```

An example [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/29kpuxvq/)

Comment: Doesn't change anything and the symbol animation on the polyline still behaving weird.